# Why unit test fail with Optional return type?

Tags: java, mockito

Consider the following codes using Mockito (version 2.23.4) for unit testing. I have no idea why the test fail. If I change a.get(null) to a.get(2L) or any Long value, the test will pass. So why is null failing when anyLong() should work for null values?

```
public class A {

    public Optional<Long> get(Long l) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        A a = Mockito.mock(A.class);
        Mockito.when(a.get(anyLong())).thenReturn(Optional.of(1L));
        Assert.assertTrue(a.get(null).isPresent());
    }

}
```

Comment: You have mocked out the method to return `Optional.of(1L)`  when it receives any Long, but not when it receives null.

Comment: Oh I see. It used to include NULL but not any more. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `anyLong()` matcher does not include `NULL` (anymore). See the documentation of [`ArgumentMatchers.anyLong()`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.19.1/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#anyLong--):

> Any `long` or non-null `Long`.
>
> Since Mockito 2.1.0, only allow valued `Long`, thus `null` is not anymore a valid value.

This is different from [Mockito 1.9.5](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.9.5/org/mockito/Matchers.html#anyLong()):

> Any `long`, `Long` or `null`.

Comment: Thanks. What if I want to return Optional.of(1L) for any Long value *and* NULL?

Comment: I just found that I can use any() and it will work with any Long value and NULL.